# Mockito latest versions support to surpress static block

Tags: mockito

I am trying to add tests using latest (5.7.0) Mockito and using Mockito.mockStatic(...)
to mock class with static methods  which works fine . However when I have class with static block it is unable to create mock and fais with `java.lang.InternalError: class redefinition failed: invalid class` .

Is this supported in latest mockito versions or still I have to live with other alternatives like powermock.

Comment: Hello, did you get a fix? same issue here

Answer (score 2):

I did face the same error and couldn't find answer in the internet, so I see that it is 1 month old question but might help someone.

The problem was that mocked class (or classes that this static block used) was not in the classpath. Before you can mock the method all static blocks or fields initializators will be run, and it causes the problem.

You can verify what class is missing in your classpath by simply trying to use this static method before mocking it. You should get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` with a class name.

When you resolve this problem, everything should work.

Comment: Unfortunately for me running static does not give me much more information.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and for me it was due to an `Error` being thrown from `instrumentation.retransformClasses`  called from `org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.inlineBytecodeGenerator`. Somewhere between there and `findOrInsert` in `net.bytebuddy.TypeCache`, the `Throwable` looses its context (for mockito-core 4.1.0 and bytebuddy 1.12.0)

In my case, the error being thrown was a `NoClassDefFoundError` for Jetty Servlet. This ultimately turned out to be a dodgy local build of a different maven module I had been working on, so clearing out my `~/.m2` and downloading a legit version fixed that right up.

You might be able to catch the `Error` being thrown in `inlineBytecodeGenerator` and taking a look at what's really going on, if this is in fact the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I encountered this issue in moving from Mockito 4 to Mockito 5.
I had a similar situation where I got messages:

```
Mockito cannot mock this class: com.example.ClassName
...  
Underlying exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
...  
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: class redefinition failed: invalid class
```

When I looked closer (and at the top of the console) I noticed it said this:

> You are seeing this disclaimer because Mockito is configured to create inline mocks.

Looking in my build.gradle, I noticed I had both of these:

```
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:5.+'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.+'
```

I realized I did not need to keep the inline one so I removed it and it worked.